# get service name by port

Tags: sockets, go

I'm writing simple net scanner and stuck at resolving service name by port number. What's the best way to do this? I supposed it should be something like python's `socket.getservbyport()` and founded [this lib](https://godoc.org/honnef.co/go/netdb), but unfortunately Dev environment bases on Windows, also I wanted built-in solution not a parsers.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type PortScanner struct {
    ip string
}

func ScanPort(ip string, port int, timeout time.Duration) {
    target := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", ip, port)
    conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", target, timeout)
    if err != nil {
        if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "too many open files") {
            time.Sleep(timeout)
            ScanPort(ip, port, timeout)
        }
        return
    }

    if err = conn.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(port, "open")
}

func (ps *PortScanner) Start(f, l int, timeout time.Duration) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    defer wg.Wait()

    for port := f; port <= l; port++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(port int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            ScanPort(ps.ip, port, timeout)
        }(port)
    }
}

func main() {
    ps := &PortScanner{ip: "127.0.0.1"}
    ps.Start(1, 65535, 500*time.Millisecond)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the code from that netdb library to load a `services` file you provide [instead of `/etc/services`](https://github.com/dominikh/go-netdb/blob/master/netdb.go#L71).

Perhaps better yet, since this is essentially just a key/value mapping, create a `ports.go` file with:

```
var tcpPorts = map[int]string{
    80: "http"
    // ...
}
```

And then do a regular map lookup.

To list all TCP ports you can do something like:

```
$ sed -E '/tcp$/!d; s!^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\s+([0-9]+)/\w+!\t\2: "\1",!;' /etc/services
1: "tcpmux",
2: "compressnet",
3: "compressnet",
5: "rje",
7: "echo",
9: "discard",
11: "systat",
13: "daytime",
17: "qotd",
19: "chargen",
.. many more ..
```